# Open source Whatsapp business API client for python

Tags: python, whatsapp

I have my own Whatsapp business account.
I want to have a client that can:

1. Alert me when I get a new message
2. Be able to send an automatic reply based on the original message I've received.

I've searched the web for ready open source python clients I can use and found only one that might be suitable - https://pypi.org/project/wabclient/
The problem - there is no documentation on how to use it, reviews etc.
Are there any other open sources I can use to achieve my goal? Any sample projects that use wabclient?

Comment: https://github.com/mukulhase/WebWhatsapp-Wrapper - https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/quickstart/python why are these not suitable?

Comment: @TinNguyen AFAIK twillo is not free. I see that both are using the web client, are there any good solutions that work with the official API?

Comment: I can't use twillo 'cause it's not free.

Comment: The other one is free. Why is using the web API wrapper insufficient for your needs? There isn't really anything else.